# Anyone know how upload imgs to mongo from react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I need upload imgs input for the user and this images will load in mongo then the user can review that images in your view, pls help!!

i have configure mi DB and mi api with post and get method and that is succes tested with postman but from client app i dont know how upload images and how do mi bd save images

I use react for the client app, and node js for the api

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The database isn't actually a place to save your images or file. You should be saving reference to the file in the database ideally. But if you want to store image or file in MongoDB only, then there is a way.

You need to convert your file into `base64` string format. Please find the snippet to convert your file to `base64` string in react.

```js
let selectedFile = "";
function onSelect () {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function () {
        // You will get base64 string of file with render.result
        selectedFile = reader.result;
    };
};
```

Now you can save it as `string` in the database. You can easily pass the content in the `src` tag of `<img />` attribute in HTML.